# Reimport updated module to python

Tags: reload

I have the following scenario in python3

`from phase_2d import phase_2d` #where phase_2d is a python file phase_2d.py

I then edit this file and want to test the changes, without having to quit python and reload everything.

```
imp.reload(phase_2d)
```

returns the error 'Type:Error: reload() argument must be module'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you imported the phase_2d class from the module phase_2d, when you call imp.reload(phase_2d), the phase_2d being passed to the reload command is the class, not the module. In order to use the reload command, you must import the actual module, or otherwise get a reference to the module. For example, you could do something like this:

```
import phase_2d
from phase_2d import phase_2d as p2d
...
imp.reload(phase_2d)
```

Or, if you really only want to import the single class from the module, you could use the inspect module to get the parent module from the class (http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmodule)

```
import inspect
from phase_2d import phase_2d
....
imp.reload(inspect.getmodule(phase_2d))
```